# remove focus style of StoreFilterField in GWT

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, extjs, gxt

I am looking for some ways to remove the x-form-foucs css style of [StoreFilterField](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-.2.1/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/StoreFilterField.html).

I have put a storeFilterFiled and some other textfield on a formPanel, if I want to typing some word into the textField, the cursor will turn back to storeFilterField after I clicked the textField, due to storeFilterField will always get focus..

Have tried to use removeStyleName("x-form-focus");, but doesn't work.

--

Updated:

After having Tangent suggested, I have used chrome developer tool and breaks on attributes modification at the StoreFilterField. And when I click other field, I have got call stack.

The stack as below:

```
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_core_El_$removeStyleName
```

has called by `com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_$triggerBlur` and the styleName been removed is "x-trigger-wrap-focus", TriggerField has been extended by StoreFilterField.

And triggerBlur() is called by TriggerField_$mimicBlur. and mimicBlur() is called by

```
focusEventPreview = new BaseEventPreview() {
  protected boolean onAutoHide(final PreviewEvent ce) {
    if (ce.getEventTypeInt() == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
      mimicBlur(ce, ce.getTarget());
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

Which is in TriggerField's onRender()

The whole stack as below:

```
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_core_El_$removeStyleName__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_core_El_2Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_core_El_2 (0.js:15459)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_Component_$removeStyleName__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_Component_2Ljava_lang_String_2V (0.js:3276)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_$triggerBlur__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_2Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_event_ComponentEvent_2V (0.js:8032)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_triggerBlur__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_event_ComponentEvent_2V (0.js:8097)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_$mimicBlur__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField_2Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_event_PreviewEvent_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Element_2V (0.js:7962)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_widget_form_TriggerField$1_onAutoHide__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_event_PreviewEvent_2Z (0.js:29870)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_util_BaseEventPreview_$onAutoHidePreview__Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_util_BaseEventPreview_2Lcom_extjs_gxt_ui_client_event_PreviewEvent_2Z (0.js:14039)
com_extjs_gxt_ui_client_util_BaseEventPreview_onPreviewNativeEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewEvent_2V (0.js:14114)
com_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewEvent_$dispatch__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewEvent_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewHandler_2V (0.js:42152)
com_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewEvent_dispatch__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_EventHandler_2V (0.js:42216)
com_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_dispatch__Ljava_lang_Object_2V (0.js:35511)
com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_EventBus_dispatchEvent__Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_Event_2Ljava_lang_Object_2V (0.js:35907)
com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_$doFire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_Event_2Ljava_lang_Object_2V (0.js:35959)
com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_Event_2V (0.js:36017)
com_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V (0.js:35860)
com_google_gwt_user_client_Event$NativePreviewEvent_fire__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_2Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_NativeEvent_2Z (0.js:42198)
com_google_gwt_user_client_Event_fireNativePreviewEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_NativeEvent_2Z (0.js:42136)
com_google_gwt_user_client_DOM_previewEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2Z (0.js:41948)
(anonymous function) (0.js:42654)
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2 (0.js:33472)
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2 (0.js:33531)
(anonymous function) (0.js:33502)
(anonymous function) (0.js:42689)
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2 (0.js:33472)
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2 (0.js:33531)
(anonymous function) (0.js:33502)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that x-form-focus is the name of the style causing the undesired behavior?  Use a browser DOM inspector (Inspect element, Firebug, etc) to find out which styles are applied to the widget.  It's also possible that the behavior you're describing is because of event handlers, not CSS styles.

Comment: Hi Tangent, it is because of event trigger, not css styles as you have suggested, thank you very much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the caution finally. That is I have used FormButtonBinding simultaneously. FormButtonBinding will call isValid() of each field in the panel which it has binding. And isValid of StoreFilterField will always doing onFilter() and focus()...

Just override isValid() as below code:

```
    filter = new StoreFilterField<Model>()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(boolean preventMark) {
            if (disabled) {
                return true;
            }
            boolean restore = this.preventMark;
            this.preventMark = preventMark;
            boolean result = validateValueWithOutOnFilter(getRawValue());
            if (result) {
                //activeErrorMessage = null;
            }
            this.preventMark = restore;
            return result;
        }

        protected boolean validateValueWithOutOnFilter(String value) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean doSelect(Store<Model> store, Model parent, Model record, String property, String filter)
        {
            ...
        }
    };
```